# How to remove columns of a CSV file in BIRT Report

Tags: java, birt

I have a csv file to be downloaded from my code in BIRT Report. I have done that, but I have some columns that are not needed for me in that csv file. So I need to remove those columns using this BIRT Report. I have searched through google but I haven't found a solution.

is it possible to remove those columns from the csv file? I am fresh to this BIRT Report. So I'm stuck in it. I did't find any code relevent to it and I haven't tried any code. so I'm confused where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do. Maybe you need to rephrase your question for a better understanding.

After you created your your Data Source for a .cvs file, you created a Data Set. There you can select the columns you need in your Data Set. See the picture below. You cannot change the content of the file, just the selection for your report.
[image: column select]
Also if your create for example a table in your report from your Data Set, you don't need to select all columns from your data set to display.

If you want to filter out some rows of your file, you can add a filter specifying the rows you want to ceep. see the second picture: (just add the rows to your Data Set with the content row2.
[image: filter]

Comment: I am not able to see the popup like your screenshot. Here is mine  http://i.stack.imgur.com/UXo8D.png

Comment: what type of data source are you using? I use a "falt file Data Source".

Comment: I use scripted data source

Comment: a scripted data source does not automatically collect the meta data about the structure of the source. Therefore you cannot see the "Select Columns" section. 
But you don't need to remove the columns from the data set. Just don't add them to display inside your report.